# servletContext.getRealPath("") returns different results tomcat7/tomcat8 bug?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

can someone explain why `servletContext.getRealPath("")` returns different results while using different version of tomcat?

- Tomcat 7: /this/is/my/path
- Tomcat 8: /this/is/my/path/ (trailing slash)

It this a bug or has someone a good explanation for this behavior (and a workaround?) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, in Tomcat 8 getRealPath("") shall return you the path with a File separator at the end. Here goes the doc: [Java doc - getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

> Gets the real path corresponding to the given virtual path.
>
> For example, if path is equal to /index.html, this method will return the absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request of the formhttp://://index.html would be mapped, where  corresponds to the context path of this ServletContext.
>
> The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper path separators.
>
> Resources inside the /META-INF/resourcesdirectories of JAR files bundled in the application's/WEB-INF/lib directory must be considered only if the container has unpacked them from their containing JAR file, in which case the path to the unpacked location must be returned.
>
> This method returns null if the servlet container is unable to translate the given virtual path to a real path.
>
> Parameters:path - the virtual path to be translated to a real pathReturns:the real path, or null if the translation cannot be performed